# How to find non-zero elements of matrix A^T * A where A is sparse (crs/ccs) matrix?

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I have very sparse large matrix `A` (`A` is a [compressed row storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR.2C_CRS_or_Yale_format.29))

I want to perform some computations over `B = A^T * A` matrix. But `B` should be sparse too due sparsity of `A`.

How i can compute "mask" of `B`? "Mask" is column indices and row offsets of compressed row storage.

Only way which i see is to iterate over rows in nested loops (by i and j) and check (i, j) element of B as non-zero if rows i and j of A have at least one common non-zero column. But i think is slow.

PS Sorry for my poor english

Comment: If someone thinks that this question is incorrect I'm open to suggestions

Comment: I don't think your assumption, that B must be sparse, is true. Just consider A=(1,..,1;0..0;0...0;0..0;...) i.e every element in the first row is 1 then every element in B will be nonzero!

Comment: I'm not sure. If A = [[1, 1],[0, 0]] then B = [[1, 0], [0, 0]]. Because only product between first row and first row is non-zero (I just checked it with numpy)

Comment: ead is correct. In your comment your B is more like A*(A^T) than  (A^T)*A

Comment: @dmuir it is my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do it in `O(n^2)`, with `n` - number of nonzero elements in the matrix `A`.

Consider `Bij=sum Aki*Akj`, `Bij` could be only then nonzero if there is a `k` with `Aki` and `Akj` - nonzero.

Iterating through all nonzero elements of `A` and through the nonzero elements of the `k`th row of `A = Ak` (consecutive access, one element in the row after another, I assume compressed row storage (crs) - for ccs you need to iterate over columns) yields the following algorithm:

```
for (k, i) in indices(nonzero(A)):
    for j in indices(nonzero(Ak)):
      Bij=nonzero
```

As both for loops need only to touch the nonzero elements of `A` in row order (this is crucial!) and the operation `Bij=nonzero` costs `O(1)`, if you use for example a hash set or a boolean field, the resulting running time must be `O(n^2)`.

With `A=[1,..,1; 0,..,0; ...; 0, ..,0]` i.e. a matrix with the first row of nonzero  element you can see, that there is really a worst case, which needs `n^2` operations.
For example:

```
A=[1,1;0,0] -> A^T=[1,0;1,0]
B=A^t*A=[1,1;1,1]
```

I'm not sure it's different from your approach, but I don't think there is something much faster, if you have no additional information about the form of the matrix `A`.